# Why is $\prod_{n}^{n-1} = 1$ and $\sum_{k=j+1}^{j}=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, discrete-mathematics, summation, recurrence-relations

> The general first-order difference equation has the form
>   $$
> x_{n+1}= a_n x_n + g_n, \quad n\geq 0, \tag 1
> $$
>   where $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N_0}$ and $(g_n)_{n\in \mathbb N_0}$ are given sequences.
>   The solution is given by
>   $$
> x_n = x_0 \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}g_k \prod_{i=k+1}^{n-1}a_i
> $$
>   where we used
>   \begin{align}
> \prod_{n}^{n-1} = 1 \tag 2 \\
> \sum_{k=j+1}^{j}=0 \tag 3
> \end{align}

I don't follow $(2)$ and $(3)$, isn't
\begin{align}
\prod_{n}^{n-1}1 = n \cdot (n-1) \quad ?\tag 4
\end{align}
And 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=j+1}^{j}1= j \quad ?\tag 5
\end{align}

Comment: This notation is used to denote an empty sum/product (one which runs over no terms). The convention is that an empty sum/product is equal to $0/1$ respectively.

Comment: What do you mean by $n\cdot\cdots\cdot(n-1)$ ?

Comment: Hi @YvesDaoust! Hmm, I guess it's wrong... What I mean is: If $n=3$, $\prod_{3}^{2}1=3\cdot 2 = 6$. Have I misunderstand the noation $\prod_{n}^{n-1}1$?

Comment: @JDoeDoe: can you explain your notation ? What do the $\cdots$ stand for ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I give you an example: If $2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 =720$, I mean $2\cdot\,  \cdots\, \cdot 6 =720$. Isn't it a correct use of $\cdots$?

Comment: I dislike the explainations given for the value of an empy product/sum in this thread. Adding some values together can always be seen as adding those same values to zero, but this last interpretation also makes sense for no terms, so an empty sum is zero. Same goes for product.

Comment: @JDoeDoe: did you even read what you wrote ? What are the numbers between $n$ and $n-1$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Aaaah! $n$ is the first number and $n-1$ is the last, so $\cdots$ doesn't make sense. I removed $\cdots$ from the equation.

Answer (score 1):

If $$\sum_{k=m}^{n+1}a_k = a_{n+1}+\sum_{k=m}^{n}a_k$$ and for example $$\sum_{k=m}^{m+2}a_k=a_m+a_{m+1}+a_{m+2},$$ then we have no "choice" but acknowledging that
$$ \sum_{k=m}^{m+1}a_k=\sum_{k=m}^{m+2}a_k\;-a_{m+2}=a_m+a_{m+1},$$
$$ \sum_{k=m}^{m}a_k=\sum_{k=m}^{m+1}a_k\;-a_{m+1}=a_m,$$
$$ \sum_{k=m}^{m-1}a_k=\sum_{k=m}^{m}a_k\;-a_{m}=0.$$
We might even go beyond this and define sums where the top index is *way* less than the lower index, But I won't delve into that.

In the end, it is a matter of **definition.**
Given a set $S$ and a map $f\colon S\to A$ into an abelian group $A$, how can we define something that is worth being called the sum of function values of $f$, and for which we want to employ the notation
$$ \sum_{x\in S}f(x)?$$
We do it by recursion and the start is the case of the empty set! We define
$$ \sum_{x\in \emptyset}f(x)=0$$
because after all $0$ is the only element of $A$ we can put our finger on.
If $S$ is non-empty, say there is some $s\in S$, then $S\setminus\{s\}$ is smaller and we may try to use recursion to define
$$ \sum_{x\in S}f(x)=f(s)+\sum_{x\in S\setminus\{s\}}f(x).$$
Fortunately (or thanks to commutativity and associativity of addition in $A$), this is well-defined, i.e., does not depend on the choice of $s$. On the other hand, this recursion works only for finite sets $S$. 
But at least, this case is perhaps less confusing that the common two-index notation $\sum_{i=n}^m$ for $\sum_{i\in \{\,k\in\Bbb Z\mid n\le k\le m\,\}}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are inconsistencies in your question statement.

In the first place, the author does specify that in case of reversed bounds you get a $0$ sum or a $1$ product. If he gives you his conventions $(2)/(3)$, you should not question them.

Then if you reject the convention and consider that reversed ranges are not equivalent to empty, you should write

$$\prod_{\color{green}{k=}n}^{n-1}1 = 1\cdot1=1 \quad \tag 4$$

and

$$\sum_{k=j+1}^{j}1= 1+1=2\tag 5.$$
[In green, my own addition.]